# My Visual Studio 2019 WPF app is setting a dll as the output when it should be an exe

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, msbuild

This is my first time trying to make a deployable program. After creating a nice little WPF XAML app that runs (i.e. I can run the executable in the bin folder), I am trying to wrap it in a setup program.

After following multiple directions online for both WiX and "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects". Both make installer packages, but they are only targeting the dll file from the WPF XAML output when I as for the "Primary Output".  It seems this is stemming from the build of the WPF project.

How do I adjust the primary output of the build process so it is included in the setup program?

Screenshot of build output specifying the dll as the output file:

[image]

**To add more details:**

This could be one `wpf(.net core)` application instead of one `wpf(.net framework)`. See the Output window in Elton's screenshot we can find the output is xx.dll instead of xx.exe.

If we create a Installer project in this solution, right-click the Installer project=>Add=>Project Output=>Primary output to contain the WPF's output in installer project, only the xx.dll is considered as wpf's output, but not xx.exe.

So after building the Installer project in VS, double-click the setup.exe(installer project's output), the wpf.exe is not well installed.

Comment: How is your installer set up? You don't have any relevant information. Take a look at [ask] and include a [mcve].

Comment: How did you set the "primary output"? In my test, there is no situation "only targeting the dll file". Any detailed info?

Comment: The setup project is extremely barebones.  The website https://codeteddy.com/2016/04/04/creating-an-msi-package-for-c-windows-application-using-a-visual-studio-setup-project/ is how one is setup and the WiX attempt followed https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html

Comment: @KyleWang I didn't set the primary output.  It is simply not grabbing the exe.  Looking at the build output of the project, it is setting the dll as the primary output.  Therefore I don't think this is a setup project issue, but a problem with the main project build.  Sorry if the discussion about the setup led the discussion astray, but I wanted to include it as context of end objective and why I am running into this in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My Visual Studio 2019 WPF app is setting a dll as the output when it
>   should be an exe.

I'm sure you're using a WPF(`.net core`) project cause yesterday I happened to reproduce same situation in my machine. As for the cause of the issue, if you're interested in it, you may get some help from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472009/generating-net-core-console-app-exe-in-visual-studio-2017). For `.net core 2.2` and earlier, if we build a console(`.net core`) project, we'll get a `xx.dll` as output by default(Use `dotnet xx.dll` to run that).

But for `.net core 3.0`, I found this situation changes. Now if we build a Console(.net core) or WPF(.net core), apart from the `xx.dll`, we'll also get an `xx.exe` now. And I checked the Updated date of [Installer Project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) and the Release date of WPF(.net core), the latest update of the Installer project is much earlier than the release of WPF(.net core), I guess maybe this is the cause? I'm not certainly sure how Installer Project recognize the output of one WPF project, but I suggest you can post this issue in [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) , if it gets enough votes, the team will consider a fix.

**Here're my workarounds which may help:**

1.Use `Add=>File` instead of `Add=>Primary Output`:

Build the WPF project in release mode, navigate to the output path and copy that path. Then right-click `Installer project`=>Add=>Files to enter that path. Choose all files in output folder and click open:

[image]

Right-click the assembly file and choose Find in Editor:

[image]

Right-click the `xx.exe`=>Create a shortcut. Then move the shortcut to `User's Desktop folder` and set the `AlwaysCreate` property to be `true`.

After that, build the installer project and install that xx.msi or setup.exe in my machine, I'll get a shortcut in desktop, double-click it will run the wpf(core) application.

2.See [this blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables), we can use command like `dotnet publish -r xxx -p:PublishSingleFile=true` to get a single-file executable which is self-extracting and contains all dependencies (including native) that are required to run your app. In this situation, you don't need a `Installer project` to deploy your project. The single executable is enough. Hint from **Lex Li** in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559280/how-do-i-make-my-setup-project-produce-an-executable).

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: That single-file publishing f-ing brilliant.  This code was for technicians on the shop floor, so a "drag this exe where you want it" solution is going to solve so many headaches down the road for maintenance.  I had used the tags version in my .csproj file adding <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier> and <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>.  Then it was as simple as build, then right clicking the project and clicking publish.

Comment: Glad to know it helps:)

Answer (score 8):

On top of **Lance** answer. You can add the publish items to your outputs near your main **Primary Output**.

1- Right-click on project and select `Add => Project Output`.
2- Choose your target project and select **Publish Items** from the list with your configuration.
3- Now you have another **Output** in your **Application Folder**.

Done. with every **Batch Build** you have your publish directory copied to application folder.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, seems to be an actual solution instead of a workaround

Comment: "Right-click on project and select Add => Project Output" context menu has Project Reference... no "Project Output" [VS2019 16.8.5]

Comment: I agree, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: I will put a note on my project to try this next time I have it open for revision.  This is a very simple code, but I know there is already a minor improvement issue in my to-do.  Once (read 'if') I get to clear my higher priority tasks to get to the minor issue, I will definitely give this a try and update the accepted answer accordingly.

Comment: This seems to include the PDB file. Is there a simple way to exclude that?

Comment: @StevenFisher Finally I used Wix to create a good installer. There would be a 2-hour video on Youtube about it

Comment: @ArminTorkashvand I've done that. It's… inelegant. But I'll continue to use that approach when it matters. Luckily, this installer has a user base of one and I don't really care if he gets the PDB. :)